# how not to show some tabs on tabbed activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-design-library

I have the following activity wich show different tabs.

```
public class BagContent extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener, CosmeListener {

String[] profileTypes;

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bag_content);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.title_activity_bag_content) + " [" + bagName + "]");
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i)).setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new FormatShortFragment();
        case 1:
            return new FormatLongFragment();
        case 2:
            return new FormatPlantFragment();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_short).toUpperCase(l);
        case 1:
            return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_long).toUpperCase(l);
        case 2:
            return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_plant).toUpperCase(l);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have and array wiht different profile types, depending on each type i have to show some tabs or others.

Actually all tabs are been showing for every profile type. I tried to insert manually the tabs on the actionbar, but then the tabs are not showing the fragments correctly. Other problem is that navigation breaks when i go to an inexistent tab on the right edge.

I need help with this, how can I select just 1 tab for a specific profile type?

for example, how can I show just the title_bag_content_format_long and his fragment for profileTypes[1]?

Any walk aroun can be good, for example remove some tabs from some profile types or any other thing.

Thanks a lot guys, I really need help with this.

EDITED

I have made some modifications:

Added a profile type parameter to SectionsPagerAdapter constructor:

```
private String profileType;
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String profileType) {
    super(fm);
    this.profileType = profileType;
}
```

Then i have modified this other methods to control the profile type:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if (this.profileType.equals(profileTypes[1])){
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FormatPlantFragment();
            }
        } else {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FormatShortFragment();
            case 1:
                return new FormatLongFragment();
            case 2:
                return new FormatPlantFragment();
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (this.profileType.equals(profileTypes[1])){
            return 1;
        }
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        if (this.profileType.equals(profileTypes[1])){
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_plant).toUpperCase(l);
            }
        } else {
            switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_short).toUpperCase(l);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_long).toUpperCase(l);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.title_bag_content_format_plant).toUpperCase(l);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This is working correctly and do the filter by profile type more versatile.
Thanks to Filpe.costa01 that gave me the push that I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning all the tabs because your method

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return 3;
}
```

return 3 tabs. Maybe you could use the SectionsPagerAdapter constructor to include the number of tabs you'd like, according to each profile wanted.

Something like this:

```
private mNumOfTabs;
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int numberOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    mNumOfTabs = numberOfTabs;
}
```

and you should replace your getCount() method for this one:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // Show 3 total pages.
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
```

Organizing your profiles in an ascendant way (low profile = small number of tabs), you can use this method like it's now

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        return new FormatShortFragment();
    case 1:
        return new FormatLongFragment();
    case 2:
        return new FormatPlantFragment();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Otherwise, you should think about the profiles and implement a new logic to retrieve the correct tabs for each profile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This can be a good way, but you gave me another idea, i will try it and comment the result.

Comment: Edited the question with the solution, thanks for help!